# Selecting and replacing randomly generated letters in Java

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to select a position in my randomly generated 10 letters and then change that randomly selected letter to change to another letter within the alphabet. I am getting caught up on how I am supposed to actually select and change this letter. I think my program is selecting a place but I cannot find out how to continue on with it. You can also ignore the userinput part, I plan to use it later.

Here is my program

```
package Stuff;

import java.util.Scanner;

import java.util.Random;

public class Stuff {

    static Scanner userinput = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

        int N = alphabet.length(), rndposition = (int) (Math.random() * 10 + 1), rndletter = alphabet.charAt(1);

        Random r = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.print(alphabet.charAt(r.nextInt(alphabet.length())));
        }
        System.out.println(r);
    }
}
```

My output is the 10 random digits plus "java.util.Random448139f0

Thanks for any help or recommendations

I am also new to this so I might've done something wrong.

**Edit:**

Here is my new program

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    int randomnumber = 0;
    int rndposition = (int) (Math.random() * 10 + 1);
    int rndletter = alphabet.charAt(1);

    Random r = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        randomnumber = r.nextInt(alphabet.length());
        System.out.print(alphabet.charAt(randomnumber));
        alphabet.replace(rndposition, rndposition + 1, rndletter);
    }
    System.out.println("\n");
}
```

The only problem I seem to be facing now is the "alphabet.replace" where it won't let me use the argument because it is not applicable for (int,int,int). Then I need to reprint the update random 10 character word and then repeat it 20 times.

Comment: What did you expect `println(r)` to print, and why did you expect that? --- What is the purpose of `N`? You never use it. --- What is the purpose of `rndposition`? You never use it. --- What is the purpose of `rndletter`? You never use it.

Comment: Note that in Java, a String is immutable, and thus cannot be changed. You will need to create a new String with some of the of the original String replaced by new values. Perhaps using a StringBuilder would be helpful here.

Comment: @FredK Or a `char[10]`, since the length is known.

Comment: FredK nice explanation. You are clearing his concept. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting "java.util.Random@6f94fa3e" printed in the same line with your 10-random letters because the "print" method in your for loop will display the current line but will not terminate it.
The "println" method, on the other hand, will print on the current line and terminate it, meaning that your next displayed text will be on a new line. For example:

```
System.out.print("This is ");
System.out.println("the same line.");
System.out.println("This is a new line.");
// Output:
// This is the same line.
// This is a new line.
```

You can enhance it by inserting the new line character at the end:

```
System.out.println("\n" + r);
```

If you are not sure why you are getting "java.util.Random448139f0" printed in the first place.
You are trying to print an object that doesn't have .toString() method implemented. In order to print a number that was generated using this object, you can put it in a variable and print it later on:

```
int randomNumber = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    randomNumber = r.nextInt(alphabet.length());
    System.out.print(alphabet.charAt(randomNumber));
}
System.out.println("\n" + randomNumber);
```

**Edit**:

Some enhancements that could be handy:

It is a good practice to declare variables on a new line, even if they are sharing the same type:

```
int N = alphabet.length();
int rndposition = (int) (Math.random() * 10 + 1);
int rndletter = alphabet.charAt(1);
```

It enhances readability, avoids confusion and potential bugs that might be introduced with such a declaration.
You may check [this](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2133373&seqNum=2) article or [this](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-141270.html#2991) to fully understand the pitfalls.

Another enhancement that comes to my mind is a camel case convention for naming variables that is not present in your code. You can refer to [this](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) page for more information.

I believe everything else will come with practice :)
Enjoy your adventure!

Comment: This helped a lot, thank you. However, I still need to replace the characters. I am using alphabet.replace(rndpositon,rndposition+1,rndletter); which won't let me use the .replace because it isn't applicable for (int,int,int). That is my main problem now, and then I will also need to repeat this 20 times

Comment: Could you please share what you got so far? You could try to edit your post and add an update : )

Comment: What are you trying to replace in your alphabet String?

Comment: A letter, to be replace by another random letter

Comment: replace() method of a String doesn't take any int arguments. It takes an old letter and a new letter. Then it replaces all occurrences of an old character with a new one. Check this out: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-char-char-